# No sooner - than construction

Tags: sentence-construction, construction

- No sooner had I spoken than I wished I kept my mouth shut.

How is it explained that "than" is used alone and without any other words and why "than" in the first place?

As a side question, how to use this construction?

Comment: Your sentence is incomplete as you have not included what it was that you said. If you don't wish to mention what it was that you said, then you can replace 'said' with 'spoken'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiomatic construction *no sooner [X] than [Y]* means that event [Y] happened **immediately** after event [X], with no passage of time between them. Both events happened in the past.

> *No sooner* had I arrived at school *than* it started to rain.

Event [X] is described in the past perfect tense with an inverted word order.

> **I had** arrived at school.
>
> No sooner **had I** arrived at school...

Event [Y] is described in the simple past tense.

> It started to rain.
>
> ...than it started to rain.

More examples:

> *No sooner* had she sat down *than* there was a knock on the door.
>
> *No sooner* had we finished one meal *than* we started planning the next.
>
> *No sooner* had I said it *than* I wished I had kept my mouth shut.

---

"No sooner" does not always have to go at the start of the sentence. Instead, we can insert it between the auxiliary verb *had* and the past participle. This is an equally correct sentence. The difference is only a matter of style.

> I had *no sooner* arrived at school *than* it started to rain.